# Converting string to date that contains 00:00:00

Tags: python

To convert a string date to date format dropping the `'00:00:00'` I use :

```
import datetime
strDate = '2017-04-17 00:00:00'
datetime.datetime.strptime(strDate, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Returns :

```
ValueError: time data '2017-04-17 00:00:00' does not match format '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'
```

Is `%H:%M:%S` not correct format ?

Comment: `%Y/%m/%d` is not the correct format for `YYYY-MM-DD` for obvious reasons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct way:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(strDate, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Notice the `-` instead of `/` in `strptime`. The date is converted to: `2017-04-17`.

If you would like to have it displayed a different way, have a look [here](http://strftime.org).